# implementing like/dislike functionality in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack-navigation

Currently i am building an app like instagra, in which I have one activity and many fragments like, home,search,user profile and so on

I am using MVVM in project, and as you can see in the image below, my home fragment is the first one, second one is user profile fragment
[image]

In home page there are posts created by users. When i click to username it goes to user profile.

The problem here is, when i like one of the posts in user fragment, i change like icon to filled red like icon and then i send a request to my backend rest api server. But when i press back button and come back home fragment, because i only change like icon in user profile fragment, home fragment doesn't know about the post i liked, that is why it shows post is not liked (It only knows when i refresh page manually,because new data comes with refreshing)

How can i implement it in the right way?

Comment: For a better answer, you should have posted snippets of code here: But what you need to do after you press back button, you have to re-initialize the viewModel that's in charge of the home fragment in override onResume function.

Comment: Are you using NavController through nav_graph to implement this ? you can pass on data in navArgs on back press / action bar click as any boolean param or if the items are finite list of item positions for which you want to refresh the list items in home fragment  or refresh the page altogether .

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options:

1. Communicate between the Fragments and do a fetch/refresh (I don't like this as it's network consuming)
2. Create a scoped object, with an in-memory-cache for storing the items and their like state. You could use a [StateFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-state-flow/) here or other stream, which is reactive by design.

For the scoped object you have multiple options also:

1. Navigation Graph or Activity scoped `ViewModel`
2. `@Singleton` or other custom scoped `Repository`

Happy to answer in more detail if something isn't clear.